# How many airports around the world have border control for incoming domestic flights?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, airports, borders, domestic-travel

I've flown to various airports around the world and whilst international flights can have complicated rules around whether you have to go through border control (eg if the country is part of Schengen or the Common Travel Area), generally domestic flights have no such requirement.
The only exception to this I've encountered is at Dublin Airport, where they put people from incoming flights through border checks regardless if they're domestic or international.
Are there any other airports which have this policy?

(NB, I'm not talking about ID checks for boarding a plane, just immigration control when arriving at your destination)

Comment: Do you have a reference that domestic passengers are put through immigration at Dublin? What does border control do if the arrivals have no travel document?

Comment: @DJClayworth I don't know of any published source, but can confirm it's the case, as there are no domestic arrival gates

Comment: Is it possible that the (rare) domestic arrivals are routed around immigration somehow?

Comment: @DJClayworth No, not possible with the airport layout. However if presenting the boarding pass and appearing Irish or British, one will normally sail through.

Comment: The other way around, but even though normally Schengen and non-Schengen flights depart from different areas, currently there are Schencen flights leaving from the non-Schengen gates at BSL, which implies going through exit passport control (though I suppose officers will probably wave through passengers with Schengen boarding passes).

Comment: @jcaron "though I suppose officers will probably wave through passengers with Schengen boarding passes" You do have to present travel documentation, but non-EU/EFTA passports aren't stamped if you have a Schengen boarding pass.

Comment: @DJClayworth I've flown CFN -> DUB quite a few times now, and every time have had to go through border control.  I do ask the border agents why I need to, but they're normally joking around so much it's hard to get a straight answer out of them.

Answer (score 1):

Morocco does for the Casablanca-Tanger-Gibraltar flight if travelling Casablanca-Tanger.

India also does for the Delhi-Thiruvananthapuram-Male flight if travelling Delhi-Thiruvananthapuram.

Comment: Where do these checks happen?  At the intermediary airports?  Or a these exit checks, rather than entry checks?

Comment: @lucas Exit check in Casablanca, re-entry check in Tanger. I assume that for Moroccans, the national ID card is sufficient in that case. Same regarding India (where a voter's ID can be used by Indians)

Comment: Interesting!  So the checks there are for those specific flights because they go on to do an international leg.  Do they also have domestic flights at the airports which don't need border checks?

Comment: @lucas Yes, any flight that's domestic-only, i.e. all domestics except the ones I mentioned